# Win32 exception was unhandled - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer, base-class-library

I 'm trying to run an .exe from a Windows Forms Application (visual c++ - VS 2012). For this reason, I added a button, in order to run the .exe, when clicked. The command I used is:

```
Process::Start("C:\\application_directory\\application.exe");
```

Build has no errors, but running Windows Forms Application fails, as image below indicates. I tried running .exe from cmd and it runs fine. What is the probrem?

*.exe is Win32 Application (visual c++ - VS 2012).*

[image]

Comment: Why are only some of your backslashes escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using single `\` in the path instead of `\\` values in some cases.  These are being interpreted as escape characters and not directory separators